# Pandas Dataframe keep rows where date is between two dates (seperate columns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this :

```
Price        From           To
 300€        2020-01-01     2020-01-07
 250€        2020-01-04     2020-01-08
 150€        2020-02-01     2020-02-04
 350€        2020-02-04     2020-02-08
```

And then I have a list of dates. For example: `list = [2020-01-03, 2020-02-04]`

I would like to keep only the rows of the dataframe where the dates are in between the `From` column and the `To` column.

So, after transformation I would have the following dataframe.

```
Price        From           To
 300€        2020-01-01     2020-01-07
 150€        2020-02-01     2020-02-04
 350€        2020-02-04     2020-02-08
```

First I thought of using a lambda with an apply but I thought it was not very efficient because my dataset is very large. Is there a simpler way to do this with pandas ?

The result would be contained in one single dataframe

Comment: Can you specify more precisely the `list` of dates? Is it guaranteed to have one entry for each row of the pandas Dataframe? Or is it a two-element list and you want to compare the first element to the `From` and the second element to `To` column in the dataframe?

Comment: The list contains a list of dates of the following format: year-month-day just (could be of type string or of type date I can convert them if needed). The dates in the list have the same format as the dates in the dataframe. There are no NAN values in the dataframe and the list will contain at least one date.

Comment: the list could contain more dates. In the example I only put 2 days but it could've been 3 dates or even 4

Comment: Okay, so which date in the list should be compared to which date in the dataframe? Or is the outcome several dataframes, one for each item in the list?

Comment: If I look at the example I gave above, I would like to take the first date in the list and keep all the rows where this date is between the From and the To. Then I would take the second date of the list and then keep also all the rows where this date is in between the From and the To dates. Is it clear enough ?

Comment: When you take the second date, do you apply the filtering to the outcome of the first iteration, or to the original dataframe. That is, do you want one final dataframe or do you want multiple dataframes in the end?

Comment: For example in pandas there is this method : data[data['colname'].isin(list)] where it looks at value of  'colname' column and if the value is also in the list then it will keep the row. Well it is the same thing with my list of dates. I want to keep only the rows where the dates are in between the From and To column

Comment: I would like one dataframe at the end

Comment: Okay. Then note that you can take the min and the max of your dates in the list and filter on those. That reduces the problem in case you many more dates. Then a simple `df.query()` should suffice. Do you run into speed problems for this scenario?

Comment: Actually, your example output doesn't work with the description. For instance, the first row would not be included if filtered on the second date as the 2nd of February is not between the 1st and 7th of January @colla.

Comment: But the row should be kept if at least one date in the list is in between the From and To

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with `numpy broadcasting`:

```
x, y = df[['From', 'To']].values.T
a = np.array(['2020-01-03', '2020-02-04'], dtype=np.datetime64)
mask = ((x[:, None] <= a) & (y[:, None] >= a)).any(1)
```

---

```
df[mask]

  Price       From         To
0  300€ 2020-01-01 2020-01-07
2  150€ 2020-02-01 2020-02-04
3  350€ 2020-02-04 2020-02-08
```

Comment: Nice solution, Shubham! You got my upvote!

Comment: Thank's @DanailPetrov happy holidays!

Comment: Thank you very much but I get only False in the mask when I should get some True. I am not sure I understand the last line (mask = ...) could you please provide a little explanation?

Comment: @colla Check `df.dtypes` the data type of `From` and `To` columns should be be `datetime64`, if not you first need to use `pd.to_datetime` to convert them to datetime type..

Comment: Both my To and From columns were converted as datetime64 : df['From'] = df['From'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

Comment: Ok I will go there

Answer (score 0):

One option is with Pandas IntervalIndex:

```py
dates = ['2020-01-03', '2020-02-04']
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.From, df.To, closed='both')

df.iloc[intervals.get_indexer_for(dates)] # for duplicates, you can use .unique
 
  Price       From         To
0  300€ 2020-01-01 2020-01-07
2  150€ 2020-02-01 2020-02-04
3  350€ 2020-02-04 2020-02-08
```